# PHP Criação de leveis com experiência

Tags: php

Eu quero criar uma classe geral que verifica a experiência dos *users* em sessão.

Variáveis de experiência:

```
$level1 = 0;
$level2 = 50;
$level3 = 100;
...
```

A minha questão e objetivo é criar algo do gênero:

```
if user tiver 0 exp, add lvl1
if user tiver 50 exp, add lvl2
if user tiver 100 exp, add lvl3
  ....
```

Começei assim a criar desta forma, mas sempre que faço *refresh* ele adiciona sempre +1 nível. Eu queria que só adicionasse 1x ao ter aquela experiência:

```
if($level) {

    $level1 = 0;
    $level2 = 50;
    $level3 = 100;
    $level4 = 150;
    $level5 = 200;      
    $level6 = 250;
    $level6 = 300; 

    if($exp == $level2) {

         $update1 = "UPDATE users_steam SET level = level + '1' WHERE steamid = '$steamid'";
         $result1 = $db->query($update1); 

    } else if($exp == $level3) {

         $update2 = "UPDATE users_steam SET level = level + '1' WHERE steamid = '$steamid'";
         $result2 = $db->query($update2);
    }

}
```

Como posso fazer com que ele pare quando verificar a experiência e adicione o novo nível?

Comment: Usar [**Array**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) deve resolver seu problema.

Comment: Bem, o que pode acontecer que é você não está zerando a experiência. Exemplo: Eu tenho uma tabela que tem exp atual e exp max, quando ele atinge a exp max eu reseto a exp atual, e aumento a exp max. Isso evita esse problema.

Comment: hum ok entendi, é uma boa solução, e como posso aumentar a segurança deste script e dos updates?

Answer (score 0):

Se é de 50 em 50 você pode simplesmente fazer:

```
$level = floor( ($exp / 50) + 1 );
```

[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8f5b076066e2cd059e6415baff4bf01a650b487)

Isto poderia ser feito na hora de exibir ao usuário, enquanto no banco de dados apenas mantem o valor em experiencia.

---

O [`floor`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.floor.php) arredonda para baixo, o resto é matemática. Supondo que `exp` seja `20` ele irá fazer `(20/50) + 1` (*=`1.4`*), o `floor` resultará em `1`, isto independe de qualquer refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Agradeço a ajuda, consegui criar uma forma mais fácil e funciona 100%
que é ao fazer *update* do Level, ele faz um *update* onde retira (-250exp) e fica com os restantes:

```
$update2 = "UPDATE users_steam SET exp = exp - '250' WHERE steamid = '$steamid'";
```

Comment: Não utilize o espaço de respostas para novos questionamentos, mas, para não ficar sem resposta, qual é o retorno de `$db->query`?